# May liquids other than water be used to kasher a material?

Tags: halacha, water, kashering-kosherization

Hagalah is when water is boiled in a pot and a utensil is thrown in to kasher it. However, if a liquid other than water, say vinegar or oil, or a solution of water and another liquid is used. Can it be used to kasher a utensil?

Answer (score 7):

It's a machlokes haposkim - see [Rema, Orach Chaim 452:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.452.5?lang=he&with=Commentary&lang2=he), citing Orchos Chaim. The Ramban says it's no good, while the Rashba allows it. So the Rema says that it shouldn't be done, but bedieved (after the fact) it's okay.

([An article at OU Kosher](https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/chocolate-covered-in-halacha-kashrus/) mentions, among other things, the relevance of this to the kashering of chocolate-manufacturing equipment, where it may be difficult to use water.)

Comment: Are you saying that one should not kasher a utensil in such a way; but if one *does* kasher a utensil in such a way, the utensil is nevertheless kosher afterwards?

Comment: @TannerSwett That seems to be the implication (although I suppose that it would be better to kasher it with water afterwards, if possible). But CYLOR, of course.

Answer (score 6):

Rema OC 452:5 writes that one cannot kasher with liquids other than water in the first instance, but that after the fact they work.